# Opencart product image with remote URL

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I have an .xls file to upload opencart products. In the file  main image is taken from the URL:
[image]

to display the image via the URL i changed on the file catalog/model/tool/image.php on line 4:

```
if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || !is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
            return HTTP_IMAGE.$filename;;
        }
```

but the site images are not displayed. How to fix this problem?
opencart Version 2.1.0.2 (rs.1)

Comment: `HTTP_IMAGE` is not defined by default.  Have you defined that as a constant anywhere?  Have you inspected the return value of `HTTP_IMAGE.$filename`

Comment: HTTP_IMAGE defined on config.php and admin/config.php. HTTP_IMAGE.$filename returned the correct link (https://yadi.sk/d/Lh1nv9QfnYtaC/PROFILDOORS/3X/3X_white_ash.jpg
) . It may be a problem with the file hosting? if you open the image link is opened on the slider

Comment: yeah that would probably be the reason.  if you can post an actual link of a live page with one of these images i could tell you for sure.

Comment: You should try and capture the image from the remote and use the caching mechanism in OC to cache and serve it locally. Any benefit received by using a CDN is given right back by resizing images instead of using the pre-configured sizes.

Comment: there is more than 20GB of information, if caching to site, hosting space is not enough

Comment: at yandex have an API to the disk. There is a special library to connect with the API. PHP library format .phar. Now you need to connect the library to the OC and use methods to obtain images from a disc.